# Books on the same shelf

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Three identical books were randomly tidied up in a cabinet containing five shelves, the probability that three books are on the same shelf is:

My thoughts:

I think the answer is $\displaystyle {1 \over 25}$

indeed,

- Alternative solution ( Combinatorics ).

  The contingencies are the functions from the set of all books $\mathcal{L}=\{L_{1},L_{2},L_{3}\}$ onto the set of all shelves  $\mathcal{E}=\{E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{5}\}$, there are  $5^3$ such functions.
  These contingencies are equally likely.
  Among these possibilities, there are $5$ which put the books on the same shelf.
- Alternative solution ( Probability )

  The probability that book $i$ either on the shelf with number $j$ is $\dfrac{1}{5}$.
  The probability that all three books are on the shelf number $j$ is therefore :  $\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^{3}$.
  The probability that they are all on the same shelf is: $5\times \left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^{3}$.
- Is my proof correct ? I'm also interested in other ways to solve it

Answer (score 2):

No matter where we place the first book, the probability each of the other two is on the same shelf as the first book is $\frac{1}{5}$. I agree, the probability is $\frac{1}{25}$.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my english

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, assuming that each of the books are placed independently, and each shelf is equally likely.

However, if the phrase "randomly tidied up" instead meant "choose a random arrangement of books", then you get a different answer.

- There are $5$ ways where they are all on the same shelf.
- There are $5\cdot 4=20$ ways where there are two on shelf, and the other on a different shelf.
- Three are $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways where they are all on different shelves.

Assuming each of these arrangements is equally likely, the desired probability is $\frac{5}{35}=\frac17$.

Comment: where did you come up with $35$

Comment: $5+10+20{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @dREaM  Thanks again